# Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster -- An error occurred when I used logstash to mongodb data in docker

Tags: mongodb, logstash

this is my logstash.conf config

```
input{
    stdin{
    }
    jdbc{
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/database"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => ""
        jdbc_driver_library => "/app/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        record_last_run => "true"
        use_column_value => "false"
        tracking_column => "id"
        last_run_metadata_path => "/app/info/station_parameter.txt"
        clean_run => "false"

        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => 100
        statement => "select * from database where id>=1"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
    }
}
output{
    mongodb{
        uri => "mongodb://192.168.1.103:27017"
        database => "mydata"
        collection => "mycollection"
    }
}
```

the error is

Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds {:event=>#, :exception=>#]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015>}

Comment: Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0xe54215b>, :exception=>#<Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster: #<Cluster topology=Unknown[192.168.1.103:27017] servers=[#<Server address=192.168.1.103:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015>}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you find this useful but we experienced the same issue in two different scenarios and resolved it, which I would like to share with you,

- client was not able to resolve the Primary Server address due to network related issues in docker files, it was resulting to this error, the mongodb server was up and running but the client was not able to resolve the address so the error was thrown.
- mongodb was restarted (or for some reason connection was lost) and when mongodb was back online, the mongoid client (ruby) was not able to re-connect again, the solution was to restart the client as well, to establish the connection again. After investigation, I would say most likely it was a version incompatibility of the driver and mongodb server.

In general, we were not able to find a permanent solution for it and it appears to be an issue with mongodb drivers, but one thing for sure, please check the compatibility of mongodb driver and the server.